# Copy ResultSet without using CachedRowSetImpl.execute()

Tags: java, hadoop, resultset, hive, cachedrowset

I'm trying to close the connection after executing a query. Before, I just create a `CachedRowSetImpl` instance and it will take care of release the resources for me. However, I am using Hive database driver from Hadoop project. It doesn't support `CachedRowSetImpl.execute()`. I'm wondering if is there any other way that allow me to copy the `ResultSet` object and close the connection?

Answer (score 6):

You can populate a `CachedRowSet` from an existing `ResultSet`:

```
public static RowSet executeQuery(String sql) throws Exception {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        con = openConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        CachedRowSet rows = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        rows.populate(rs);
        return rows;
    }finally{
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        con.close();            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Using hive as well and I get a "method not supported" error on the .populate call.